# QTableWidget memory violation

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qtablewidgetitem

I want to reset color inside a QTableWidget but I get a memory violation error when `i = j = 1`. Note that `col = 3` and `row = 8`.

```
int col= ui->ServiceTableWidg->columnCount();
int row=ui->ServiceTableWidg->rowCount();

for(int j=0 ; j<row ; j++)
{
    for (int i=0 ; i<col ; i++)
    {
        if (ui->ServiceTableWidg->item(i,j) != NULL)
        {
            ui->ServiceTableWidg->item(i,j)->setBackground(Qt::white);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First correct the order of row and column, should be item(row, column).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have no items in your QTableWidget. Firstly, you must create them by calling setItem() method, for example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ui->tableWidget->rowCount(); i++)
    for(int j = 0; j < ui->tableWidget->columnCount(); j++)
        ui->tableWidget->setItem(i, j, new QTableWidgetItem(tr("some")));
```

And your check for NULL is wrong. Use dynamic_cast, for example:

```
if(QTableWidgetItem *item = dynamic_cast<QTableWidgetItem *>(ui->tableWidget->item(i, j)))
    item->setBackground(Qt::black);
```